# Is something in the 'where' clause in Haskell only calculated once?

Tags: haskell, where-clause

When I have the following code:

```
func n = m ++ [1] ++ m ++ [0] ++ m
    where m = func2 n
```

How many times is the func2 function called? Only once, in the where clause? Or is it just calculated again every time I use m?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe it's not evaluated at all (the joy of laziness) - but if it is, it should only be evaluated once - if you like, you can try for yourself with [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace):

```
import Debug.Trace(trace)

func n = m ++ [1] ++ m ++ [0] ++ m
  where m = func2 n

func2 n = trace "called..." [n]
```

Here is an example in GHCi:

```
λ> func 3
called...
[3,1,3,0,3]
```

And here is one where you see that it might not get called (till you finally need to evaluate it):

```
λ> let v = func 4

λ> v
called...
[4,1,4,0,4]
```

See: at first it is not called - only when you finally evaluate `v` (to print it) you get the call.

Answer (score 8):

Carsten's answer (the value will be computed at most once) is correct as long as you have not disabled the monomorphism restriction. If you have, then `m` might have a polymorphic inferred type that involves a type class, and then `m` is not really a normal value, but rather a function that takes a type class dictionary and produces a value. Consider this example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Debug.Trace(trace)

func n = m ++ [1] ++ m ++ [0] ++ m
  where m = func2 n                     -- m :: Monad t => t a (where n :: a)

func2 n = trace "called..." (return n)  -- func2 :: Monad t => a -> t a
```

Then evaluating `func 3` in ghci prints

```
called...
[3,1called...
,3,0called...
,3]
```

Comment: thanks - very good point - I indeed did not think of  this here at all. It's really hard to give correct answers on Haskell when it comes to details like this - there is usually an extension that renders your intuition worthless :*(

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Carstan's and @Reid Barton's answers, it also depends on whether or not you are running compiled code or not, e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Debug.Trace(trace)

func n = m ++ [1] ++ m ++ [0] ++ m
  where m = func2 n                     -- m :: Monad t => t a (where n :: a)

func2 n = trace "called..." (return n)

main = let xs = func 3 :: [Int]
       in print xs
```

In `ghci` running `main` prints out `called` 3 times. When compiled, however, it only prints out `called` once when using `-O2`. (Tested with 7.10.2.)

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? I only have 7.10.1, but I see `called` printed 3 times when compiled as well. But certainly optimizations can also affect this behavior in general.

Comment: Yes - I was compiling with -O2. I'll clarify the answer.